# Get only an array value in ascending order?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get only an array value per time from first to last (ascending order):

```
$array = array('Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    do {
      echo $array[$i]; die;
    } while ($array[$i] == $i);
}
```

The code above is only a small demo, it doesn't work at all.
I can't get to store the next single values into the variable.

**The base of this is really simple:**
$variable stores only "Text 1", and after re-accessing PHP file, $variable stores only "Text 2", then only "Text 3", then only "Text 4" and final it returns to "Text 1".

Comment: The question *itself* is a little confusing. It sounds like your lecturer simply wants something along the lines of `$array = 'text 1'; $array = 'text 2';`. It could be that you're expected to use something like `.push()` though.

Comment: Use a for loop. `$array = array('Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4');
$count = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  echo $array[$i];
}`

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla tried it and it returns all values.

Comment: Inside the loop, you need to use one item at a time, `$varname = $array[$i]` contains `Text 1` in the first loop, use it for what you want and then it'll automatically move that variable to `Text 2`. I just showed you how to loop through a list, the logic needs to be written by you.

Comment: I was using `array_rand` but it provides the values randomly and I want it to be in ascending and as a loop.

Comment: What's the issue in accessing the item and doing whatever you want with it inside the loop?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I'll take a look now!

Comment: @ScottWillsleans **I want to get only an array value per time** What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Bluetree I want my array values to be single stored into an unique variable per time in ascending order.

Comment: @ScottWillsleans when you say time.do you want it store it like per specific time(sec/min/hour/etc)?Ex. every 1sec you will store value in variable.

Comment: @Bluetree I've updated the post with more info.

Comment: @Bluetree the last way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use `session` for this. No need to use loop. Just if else statement if the current_index session is set and less than the total array index. then print and increment our current_index else go back to 0.

**CODE**

```
session_start();
$array = array('Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4');

if(isset($_SESSION['current_index']) && $_SESSION['current_index'] < count($array)){
    echo $array[$_SESSION['current_index']];
    $_SESSION['current_index'] = $_SESSION['current_index'] + 1;
}else{
    echo $array[0];
    $_SESSION['current_index'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: When you re-accessing PHP file for the first time. it will return 'Text1' only. when you visit again the php file that contains this code. it will return text2? and so on..

Comment: Without leaving the main sense of the question, can you update the code to be only one single random value without duplicates?  Because I've realized is much better. Appreciate!

Comment: You're correct! I want it too that way, if possible.

Comment: It's perfectly working well as expected! Have see you the other code about randomize it without duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this order apply to all users of website you need to save latest one in the Database or File or In-memory databases. and each time get next index of saved index.

If this happen for each user save index in the session and each time show next index.

be aware you should reset session or saved variable when it achieve to count of array.

Comment: Its usage is for a simple quoting page.

Comment: this rule apply for all visitors of your website or just active sesions.

Answer (score 0):

there have a function in php. you can try this.

$array = array('Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3', 'Text 4');

asort($array);